# .mwb forward engineering script export in table dependency order instead of alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We have a "gold" copy of our mysql database schema called `gold.mwb`.  Whenever we add or remove tables/triggers etc we change this gold copy.  We then using the options in `MySQL workbench Export -> Forward Engineer SQL Create Script` create a `gold-beginnings.sql` file that contains all the creates needed to create a fresh instance of our database.

The problem we're facing is that this .sql export is in **Alphabetical** order and not **table dependency order** so as our database has now grown to over 400 tables we have to painfully go through and hand run the pieces in dependency order.

So my question is - Is there some flag somewhere that will let the MySQL export do it in table dependency order or was this just a gross oversight from the desingers of the export utility?

Has anyone come up with a nice work around if no flag exists?

Comment: Isn't there an sql mode set in the script to disable FK checks? Ordering tables might not work in general, especially if you have recursive dependencies. Things also get more complex if there are views involved (which is why usually first placeholders are created for views and then later they are removed and the real views are created).

Comment: There are options to not add the FK constraints as part of the table creates. I hadn't really considered the recursive dependency issue...but you're right - that does pose a problem.  Perhaps then their is not a good solution but to leave it in alphabetical order as it currently is.

Comment: After further discussion with a colleague, only poorly normalized schema's would run into recursive dependencies involving 2 separate tables, so we're back to where a properly designed database could export a valid and working .sql create script including foreign keys.

Comment: if you like you can file a feature request at http://bugs.mysql.com to get a better option in MySQL Workbench.